# Facebook App Wall Comments

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When a user adds a comment to a post on the wall of an App Profile page, the app page owner can click a box and select Remove Comment.

Now Im trying to use graph api to access those comments. so I try curl -X DELETE https://graph.facebook.com/long_comment_ID?access_token=apptoken and I get {"error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action"}}

I don't see how this makes sense.

Comment: does your app have the `publish_stream` permission?

Comment: well that's the question why would it need that permission if the person can post on the wall without logging into the app? all they have to do is like the page.

Answer (score 0):

The app doing the deleting has to have the correct [permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) to delete the wall post. As [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) describes:

> You can delete a post as long as your application created the post. You delete a post by issuing an HTTP DELETE request to the POST_ID object with `publish_stream` permission.

Your app can get these permissions from either the creator of the post, or an admin of the page, i.e. any user who you would expect to be able to delete the post. Thus, either an admin or the user has to log in to your app and give it the `publish_stream` permission for it to delete the post.

**Note**: Facebook fan/app pages are treated differently from personal wall pages: normally apps can't delete a post on a *person's* wall that was created by a different app. With fan pages this restriction is not present. You do need the `publish_stream` permission though.